# Populate table with search of keywords in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, phpmyadmin

first post here. I an very new to PHP and with all the research I've done on the internet, this code is the closest thing I can find to being close to my answer.

Question: I am trying to get book data from my local database in PhpMyAdmin that is stored from users. Users will search a keyword and it will show the results of closely matched items in a table. Just like craigslist when you type in a keyword and it shows related results but this time, it's in a table with "ISBN, Title, Author, Class, Edition" as the fields. I am connected with a database I created locally in PhpMyAdmin called nextbook.

Here is the entire file "View_Search_Results_Table.php" but split into 2 parts:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['search'])) {


       $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];

       $query = "SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE CONCAT('ISBN', 'Title',
                'Author', 'Class', 'Edition') LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";

       $search_result = filterTable($query);

    }

    else {
       $query = "SELECT * FROM books";
       $search_result = filterTable($query);
    }


   function filterTable($query)
   {
   $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "Admin1", "local", "nextbook");
   $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
   return $filter_Result;
   }

?>



 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>

     <meta charset="UTF-8" >

     <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
     </script>
     <script src="http://ie7-
      js.googlecode.com/svn/version2.1(beta4)/IE9.js">
     </script>

     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
      maximum-scale=1">


     <link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"
     />
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-
      1.4.5.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<form action="View_Search_Results_Table.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="Value To Search">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Filter"><br><br>

    <table border="1px solid black;">
        <tr>
            <th>ISBN</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Edition</th>
       </tr>

    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['ISBN'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Title'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Author'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Class'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Edition'];?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile;?>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what's your problem with the code? Your search SQL statement is not going to fetch you anything unless the search string provided is going to match all fields exactly as its in the database. If you only search by one or few fields it will never return any thing.

Comment: The problem is that it will actually show a table of just all the results. When I enter something into the field and click the Filter button, it won't populate anything, just a blank table. How would I fix this exactly, I need it to be able to find words similar to entries in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you tell me what your $_POST['valueToSearch'] value look like? Is this generated from just one input field?

Most likely what you be needing is a updated query. To start with try..

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `ISBN` LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%' OR `Title` LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%' OR 
                `Author` LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%' OR `Class` LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%' OR `Edition` LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
```

This query need to be further refined but I need to know more about your inputs and tables.

Comment: Yeah the input field is just going to be one, single entry. The fields in the 'books' table are: ISBN(primary key), Price, Title, Author, Edition, Class, Book_Condition, school_choice.

Comment: Try my updated query above. I had mistakes in it before: I had the field names enclosed in inverted comas instead of the special character (`).

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you so much for the help, I really, really appreciate it!!